# Then which of the following statements are true?[CSIR-2018-December]

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

Let $\{u_1,u_2,..., u_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb {C^n}$ as column vectors. Let $M=(u_1,u_2,...,u_{k})$ and $N=(u_{k+1},u_{k+2},...,u_{n})$ and $P$ be a $k \times k$ diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,..., \alpha_k \in \mathbb R$. Then which of the following statements are true?

(A) Rank($MPM^*)=k$ whenever $\alpha_i \neq \alpha_j$, $1\leq i,j \leq k.$

(B)Trace $(MPM^*)=\sum_{i=i}^k\alpha_i$

(C)Rank $(M^*N)=\min(k,n-k)$

(D)Rank$(MM^*+NN^*)<n$

Let $
    u_1= \begin{bmatrix}
           u_{11} \\
           u_{21} \\
           \vdots \\
           u_{n1}
         \end{bmatrix}$, $
    u_2= \begin{bmatrix}
           u_{12} \\
           u_{22} \\
           \vdots \\
           u_{n2}
         \end{bmatrix},\dots,$ $
    u_n= \begin{bmatrix}
           u_{1n} \\
           u_{2n} \\
           \vdots \\
           u_{nn}
         \end{bmatrix}.$
By Matrix multiplication,

I got $MPM^*$ $
    = \begin{bmatrix}
           \alpha_1. |u_{11}|^2&0 &\dots &0 \\
           0 &\alpha_2. |u_{22}|^2&\dots &0\\
           \vdots \\
           0&0&\dots &\alpha_k. |u_{kk}|^2
         \end{bmatrix}$
If any any of $\alpha_j=0$ then, (A) is false. Trace$(MPM^*)=\sum_{i=1}^k|u_{ii}|^2\alpha_i=\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i(\because$ $\langle u_i,u_j\rangle=\delta_{ij})$ . So,(B) is true. Hence (B) is the correct answer. Is there any theoretical approach which reduce the calculations? How do I prove (C) and (D) are false?

Comment: Observe that $M^*N$ is a $k \times (n-k)$ matrix. So $\text {Rank}\ (M^* N) \leq \text {min}\ \{k,n-k \}.$ Take $n=2$ and $k=1.$ Take the standard ordered basis $e_i$ to get the contradiction to the fact that

Comment: Then $$M= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$N = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$ What is $M^*N$ then?

Comment: You may also take $n=3$ and $k=1$ then by taking $u_i=e_i$ we get $$M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$N= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$ Then you get $M^*N = (0\ 0).$ So $$\text {Rank}\ (M^*N) = 0 \neq 1 = \text {min}\ \{1,2 \}.$$ So $(3)$ is false.

Comment: For the above example we get $MM^* + NN^* = I_3.$ Which disproves $(4)$ as well. Therefore only $(2)$ is the correct option.